# Right-side text limit working erratically while changing the font

Tags: matlab

Please note that I have already posted this question @ [mathworks.com](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1712065-right-side-text-limit-working-erratically-while-changing-the-font) but did not get any answer.

Let me try to explain a slight problem that I am facing.
In this figure, you can see that I have font “Monospaced” with font size 14. The right-hand text limit is place at 75th column. As you can see from the code, the line terminates at 75th position and then goes to the next line.
[image]

Now, if I change the font to say, “Comic Sans”, keeping the same font, the ‘right-hand text’ limiting line moves to a new position. But strangely, the text terminates not at the position where the line is shown, but in the same place where initially the ‘right-hand text limit’ was there.
[image]

I checked it for other fonts also, but still the problem persists. Any idea of what is happening?

Using Matlab R2021b.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `right hand text limit` setting you show is set at 75 _columns_, it means 75 characters, regardless of how much space they take on the screen. Different fonts will have different character horizontal size and spacing, but the return to the next line is always after the 75th character. As for the line, it can only be placed accuractely with _monospaced_ fonts (every character takes the same horizontal space), with other fonts, nobody can accurately place the line without knowing what characters the line will contain. Try to fill a line with `i` and another with `m`, then compare their size

Comment: @Hoki thanks for the input. But, `i` and `m` means ?

Comment: I meant try to use a non-monospaced font, then fill a line with `iiiii...` until it goes to the next line (you'll have 75 `i` on your line), then fill the next line with `mmmmm...` until it goes to the next line (once again you'll have 75 `m`). Then compare the horizontal width of each line, you'll see it is quite different. That's why the editor cannot accurately predict where the line end will be on a non-monospaced font, because the position of the end of line marker depends on the content of the line (wich the editor doesn't know in advance).

Comment: Then to complete the demonstration do the same thing but this time with a monospaced font, both lines will end exactly at the same point (so it's easy for the editor to predict where the line end is).